# Swift equivalent of Array.componentsJoinedByString?

Tags: swift, xcode6

In Objective-C we can call `componentsJoinedByString` to produce a string with each element of the array separated by the supplied string. While Swift has a `componentsSeparatedByString` method on String, there doesn't appear to be the inverse of this on Array:

```
'Array<String>' does not have a member named 'componentsJoinedByString'
```

What is the inverse of `componentsSeparatedByString` in Swift?

Answer (score 126, accepted):

## Swift 3.0:

Similar to Swift 2.0, but API renaming has renamed `joinWithSeparator` to `joined(separator:)`.

```
let joinedString = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].joined(separator: ", ")

// joinedString: String = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

See [Sequence.join(separator:)](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/sequence/1641243-joined) for more information.

## Swift 2.0:

You can use the `joinWithSeparator` method on `SequenceType` to join an array of strings with a string separator.

```
let joinedString = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"].joinWithSeparator(", ")

// joinedString: String = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

See [SequenceType.joinWithSeparator(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_SequenceType_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/intfm/SequenceType/s:FeRq_Ss12SequenceTypezqqq_S_9GeneratorSs13GeneratorType7ElementSS_SsS_17joinWithSeparatoruRq_S_zqqq_S_9GeneratorS0_7ElementSS_Fq_FSSSS) for more information.

## Swift 1.0:

You can use the `join` standard library function on `String` to join an array of strings with a string.

```
let joinedString = ", ".join(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

// joinedString: String = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Or if you'd rather, you can use the global standard library function:

```
let joinedString = join(", ", ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"])

// joinedString: String = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
```

Comment: For symmetry, I also noticed there's a global `split` function, although it looks slightly cumbersome to use. There's also no `split` method on `Array` at all that I can see, unfortunately.

Answer (score 7):

The componentsJoinedByString is still available on NSArray, but not on Swift Arrays. You can bridge back and forth though.

```
var nsarr = ["a", "b", "c"] as NSArray
var str = nsarr.componentsJoinedByString(",")
```

Comment: Swift array componentsSeparatedByString works for me in playground with XCode Beta 3 without bridging. Can you try this? var commaSeperatedStr = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5"
var arrayFromCommaSeperatedStr : Array = commaSeperatedStr.componentsSeparatedByString(","). Why not opposite is not couldn't understand.

Comment: yeah that's valid. the question was about the opposite though

Comment: I hit enter early i was writing why not opposite is not.

Comment: I think it's because it's still bridging to nsstring. If you command click on that method it brings you to the foundation framework

Comment: A Sequence is not an array... I still don't have a viable answer here, since converting to NSString and back is.. well... lame. I think ".reduce" may work here, but I'm not through with it yet.